# Send SMS On order to user

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, event-observer, ce-1.7.0.2

I want to send SMS when any user order any product and Dispatch. eg.

> Thank You for shopping with us. Your Order# _______ for Rs _____. It will be dispatched shortly.

And

> Your Order have been shipped through Firstflight & Docket No. is _________ . For queries call -------

I have one India sms provider company tied up with my client. I am not able to figure out event observer and page where to put my code.

Comment: Best solution i found https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Comment: You can use free extension http://springedge.com/magento-sms-extension-module-free.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) for sending sms on the new order use following event.

```
<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
</checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

2) for sending smsm on the shipment use the following event.

```
<sales_order_status_after>
</sales_order_status_after>
```

and in the observer method check the order status

```
public function confirmation_of_shipment($observer){
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order_inc_id = $order->getIncrementId();
    $state= $order->getStatus();
    if($state == "complete"){
        // order status complete means i had created shipment
        // ur sms sending code comes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Use sales_order_shipment_save_after for shipment.